# Bad credentials error when login

Tags: php, symfony

I have a method in the controller to add users in database:

```
// Ajouter
public function ajouterAction()
{
    $user = new User() ; // créer l'entité
    $user->setUsername('test2');
    $user->setPassword('testpass');
    $user->setSalt('saltpass');
    $user->setRoles(array('ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER'));

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $em->persist($user);

    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirect( $this->generateUrl('store_produit_index'));

}
```

user table :

```
id | username | pasword  | salt     | roles
---------------------------------------
27 | test2    | testpass | saltpass | a:2:{i:0;s:10:"ROLE_ADMIN";i:1;s:9:"ROLE_USER";}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
30 | winzou   | winzou   | wizou    | a:0:{}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When I connect with the username `winzou` for example, it works fine but when I connect with the username `test2` the form returns the error: `Bad credentials`

Answer (score 0):

Your password is not being encrypted when you save it, it should be.  When you login, symfony is encrypting the password the user entered and looks for the encrypted version in the database.

This might help: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/registration_form.html

Comment: but the others users passwords are not encrypted also and they work well , I can login with username (winzou) and pawssword (winzou) for exemple but can't with username (test2) !!!
Why one work and the other not ?!!

Answer (score 0):

I have cleared the field 'salt' manually in the 'user' table that is to encrypt the password, and it works fine now! But is Symfony2 automatically includes this field is to encrypt passwords? Is the word 'salt' is a specified value and reserved in Symfony2?